# Several Devices became UNCLAIMED after reboot

Tags: drivers, kernel

I've been running Ubuntu 22.04 since it came out. The last reboot prior to the problem
was 42 days with no issue. During that period I took all the updates that apt offered, but didn't reboot. I run Canonical's Livepatch (Landscape) so rebooting isn't critical.

After 42 days I did manually reboot for some logistical reason, and after boot several devices including Audio and Bluetooth show up in lshw as UNCLAIMED, and of course don't work. Their drivers don't show up in lsmod.

How can I diagnose/fix this. I have to guess that some patch or kernel update is catching me, but there are many that went in during the 42 days.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. Apparently when apt-get updated the kernel it didn't add the corresponding package linux-modules-extra-XXXX. I added it manually, problem solved. Should have found it sooner.